# Clasp run - Error: Local client credentials unauthenticated. Check scopes/authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

[image]

I'm trying to locally run apps script after installing clasp. So far I have logged in and pulled the scripts locally. Now following https://github.com/google/clasp:

```
$ clasp login
Logging in globally...
� Authorize clasp by visiting this url:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fai  


Authorization successful.

Default credentials saved to: ~\.clasprc.json (C:\Users\me\.clasprc.json).

$ clasp run testGET
Error: Local client credentials unauthenticated. Check scopes/authorization.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to sign in locally. Login with `creds.json`. Create a oauth client in same GCP as  the function `testGET` and you'll receive the creds file. See [here](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/run.md)

Comment: @TheMaster , In the instructions that you linked to it says that clasp should be > 2, but the npm version is 1.7

Comment: @user61629 the ability to execute a function was originally in the 2.0 branch but was recently merged and released as 1.7

Comment: Thanks very much @tehhowch !